# How to make the rule is executed as expected flow in drools

Tags: drools

The the following logic:

```
if (order.getPrice()<200 ) {  
   order.setPrice(order.getPrice()-10);  
} else {  
   order.setPrice(order.getPrice()-20);  
   if (order.getPrice()<200 ) {  
     //do nothing  
    }else {  
      order.setFreeShip("true");  
    }  
}
```

for above logic, if I want to implement in drools rule.

```
rule "rule 1"  
when   
    $o:Order ( amount<200);  
 then   
    $o.setPrice($o.getPrice()-10);  
end  

rule "rule 2"  
when   
    $o:Order (amount>200);  
 then   

    $o.setPrice($o.getPrice()-20);  

end
```

If the fact's price is 210, the rule2 is activated then the rule1 will be fired. That is not expected. I don't want to retract(). So is there any better solution for this issue?

And can I specify the sequential rule once a rule is executed like a token mechanism.

Thanks.

Comment: Note: Think about what happens if your `amount` is **equal** to 200.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't specify sequential for just one rule or group of rules. You'll need to create a flag and use it as a guard, for example:

```
rule "rule 1"  
when   
    $o:Order ( amount<200);  
    not: Flag(object=$o)
 then   
    $o.setPrice($o.getPrice()-10);  
    insert( new Flag($o) );
end  

rule "rule 2"  
when   
    $o:Order (amount>200); 
    not: Flag(object=$o)
 then   
    $o.setPrice($o.getPrice()-20);  
    insert( new Flag($o) );
end
```

and

```
public class Flag {
  private final Object object;
  public Flag(Object o) {
    this.object = o;
  }

  //add getter for object
  //delegate equals and hashcode to object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

rule "NYuser_Rule"

```
no-loop true
ruleflow-group "EvalLoopcondition"
when
    m:HelloProcessModel(userlocation in ("NewYorkUser"), count < 4)
then
    m.setLoopcondition(6);update(m);
```

end

rule "ChileUser_Rule"

```
no-loop true
ruleflow-group "EvalLoopcondition"
when
    m:HelloProcessModel(userlocation in ("ChileUser"), count < 3)
then
    m.setLoopcondition(5);update(m);
```

end

Something like this can help you out.